# API Request from dictionary to CSV, line by line Python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

This works for my issue below! If someone can help me, is there a better way to read the headers instead of hard-coding it. Since this is an API call, I'm thinking the request headers can change in API updates as its a fieldname.

```
#
class Csv:

    def __init__(self, JSONDict):
        self.JSONDict= JSONDict

    def json2csv(self):
        try:
            with open('test' + '.csv', 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
                fieldnames=['icao_address', 'timestamp', 'latitude', "longitude", "altitude_baro", "heading",
                "ground_speed", "vertical_rate",'squawk_code' ,"on_ground", "callsign",  "tail_number", "collection_type",
                "flight_number", "origin_airport_iata", "destination_airport_iata"]
                csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
                csv_writer.writeheader()
                for key in self.JSONDict:
                    for item in key:
                        csv_writer.writerow(key)
        except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
            pass
```

In my return object from the API request I have 5,000 more of this, so this is an example.

```
{
  "target": {
    "icao_address": "0C208E",
    "timestamp": "2020-02-14T17:58:32Z",
    "latitude": -6.016251,
    "longitude": -60.300743,
    "altitude_baro": 36000,
    "heading": 300.0,
    "ground_speed": 480.0,
    "vertical_rate": 0,
    "on_ground": false,
    "callsign": "CMP215",
    "tail_number": "HP-1831CMP",
    "collection_type": "terrestrial",
    "flight_number": "CM215",
    "origin_airport_iata": "GIG",
    "destination_airport_iata": "PTY"
  }
}{
  "target": {
    "icao_address": "345042",
    "timestamp": "2020-02-14T17:58:35Z",
    "latitude": 43.70636,
    "longitude": 1.31352,
    "altitude_baro": 36000,
    "heading": 350.0,
    "ground_speed": 460.0,
    "vertical_rate": 0,
    "on_ground": false,
    "callsign": "VLG83WG",
    "tail_number": "EC-MHB",
    "collection_type": "terrestrial",
    "flight_number": "VY8306",
    "origin_airport_iata": "BCN",
    "destination_airport_iata": "AMS"
  }
}{
  "target": {
    "icao_address": "0200FB",
    "timestamp": "2020-02-14T17:58:35Z",
    "latitude": 38.503961,
    "longitude": -2.120789,
    "altitude_baro": 35000,
    "heading": 230.0,
    "ground_speed": 440.0,
    "vertical_rate": 0,
    "squawk_code": "5764",
    "on_ground": false,
    "callsign": "RAM931G",
    "tail_number": "CN-RGK",
    "collection_type": "terrestrial",
    "flight_number": "AT931",
    "origin_airport_iata": "GVA",
    "destination_airport_iata": "CMN"
  }
}{
  "target": {
    "icao_address": "E07246",
    "timestamp": "2020-02-14T17:58:37Z",
    "latitude": 40.860528,
    "longitude": 9.897371,
    "altitude_baro": 28475,
    "heading": 240.0,
    "ground_speed": 470.0,
    "vertical_rate": 640,
    "on_ground": false,
    "callsign": "ARG1141",
    "tail_number": "LV-GIF",
    "collection_type": "terrestrial",
    "flight_number": "AR1141",
    "origin_airport_iata": "FCO",
    "destination_airport_iata": "EZE"
  }
}{
  "target": {
    "icao_address": "AD1C11",
    "timestamp": "2020-02-14T17:58:37Z",
    "latitude": 40.209449,
    "longitude": -76.836631,
    "altitude_baro": 34000,
    "heading": 240.0,
    "ground_speed": 330.0,
    "on_ground": false,
    "callsign": "AAL1382",
    "tail_number": "N944AN",
    "collection_type": "terrestrial",
    "flight_number": "AA1382",
    "origin_airport_iata": "EWR",
    "destination_airport_iata": "DFW"
  }
}
```

Comment: `csv.DictWriter` is a likely candidate. Is the data in `msg` and is there a known set of key/value pairs you want to save?

Comment: yes, should i append the contents of ms['target'] into a list and then loop through it. append headers and then rows.

Comment: Normally, you'd write the csv as you go. Only go through an intermediate list if there is some reason why you might decide not to write the file after all.

Comment: As an aside, I don't think you need the `global` declarations. A function can use existing globals from the module namespace without any declaration. The global is only useful when the function creates the variable in the module namespace. In the case of FILENAME for instance, you clearly expect the variable to exist before calling this function.

Comment: i got it to work!

Comment: updated with my code now

Comment: also the reason I used global declarations was because I kept getting the refrenced before assignment error. But I removed it for FILENAME as you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close. Since you already have a list of dicts you can use `csv.DictWriter.writerows` for most of the work. You just need to pull the `"target"` subdictionary out of each. I trimmed your data down a bit for the example.

```
import csv

data = [{
  "target": {
    "icao_address": "0C208E",
    "timestamp": "2020-02-14T17:58:32Z",
    "latitude": -6.016251,
    "longitude": -60.300743,
  }
},{
  "target": {
    "icao_address": "345042",
    "timestamp": "2020-02-14T17:58:35Z",
    "latitude": 43.70636,
    "longitude": 1.31352,
  }
},{
  "target": {
    "icao_address": "0200FB",
    "timestamp": "2020-02-14T17:58:35Z",
    "latitude": 38.503961,
    "longitude": -2.120789,
  }
}
]

fieldnames = ["icao_address", "timestamp", "latitude", "longitude"]

with open("test.csv", "w", newline="") as csv_f:
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_f, cols)
    csv_writer.writeheader()
    csv_writer.writerows(datum["target"] for datum in data)

print(open("test.csv").read())
```

Comment: hi tdelaney, I updated my code (i couldn't get yours to work on the original request read) but I made a new class to represent it instead. I've also attached a structure of the JSON and print out of my terminal. I'm still not getting it to print anything out to the csv file.

Comment: Thanks for the update (isolating to just the csv bits is great!) but its still not clear what your json looks like. You show a single dict containing a single "target" dict. You get a key then do a for loop on it, which is iterating "t", "a", "r",... Perhaps another update with the real json structure but only showing a few fields per dict in a working example I can copy and execute. The details matter on this one!

Comment: Updated with my code, and example of the Dictinonary. It sits within a list, so that's why I am looping in on the first attempt.

Comment: I've also got it to output to a CSV file with my updated code and have proper headers. Not getting the rows bit down!

Comment: Thanks for all your help, once I have enough points I will upvote this.